# Is it possible to insert and use JSON formatted javascript variables into MongoDB?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, mongodb

I'm trying to format a huge js file so I can insert it into a MongoDB collection and read it via AJAX but I'm having trouble with the syntax.  It goes something like this:

```
var MyVariable1 = [ { 
  ThingsToGet: [ 
  { 
     first_thing: "SOMETHING ONE",
     second_thing: [[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 4], [4, 4], [5, "x"], [6, "x"]]
     third_thing: 0,
     fourth_thing: []
     },{ 
     first_thing: "SOMETHING TWO",
     second_thing: [[1, 0], [2, 5], [3, 4], [4, 4], [5, "x"], [6, "x"]],
     third_thing: 0,
     fourth_thing: []
     },{ 
     first_thing: "SOMETHING THREE",
     second_thing: [[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 4], [4, 4], [5, 2], [6, 2]],
     third_thing: 0,
     fourth_thing: []
     },
   ]
   }
 ];


 var MyVariable2 = [ { 
     ThingsToGet: [ etc, etc, etc...
```

I plan on querying it with PHP:

```
$variable_to_send_to_jquery = "MyVariable1";

$filter = array(
    'var'=>"MyVariable1";
);


$results = $collection->findone($filter);
```

Comment: Is this a one time thing or something you routinely want to do?

Comment: It seems practical for this project even though it's a little strange, if that's what you mean.  There are tens of thousands of these variables.

Comment: No, do you need to insert using JSON syntax frequently? If not, I'd suggest you use Node.JS to insert the data in it's JSON form and then use PHP for your queries.

Comment: I only need to insert it once but I need to query it frequently.  I just need Mongo to store the variables and not allow it to be downloaded all at once.  I'm not sure about the syntax that would make it possible to pass the query along to jquery as a javascript variable.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest if this is a one time thing that you get [Node.JS](http://www.nodejs.org) installed and use code like follows if you've got a lot of pre-existing JSON-like files to load (the syntax you have is actually JavaScript). While I don't understand your data model (and changed it a tiny bit so it would compile), basically all I've done is to create one variable that contains an array of all of the "variables" that you add.

By putting them in a single array, you can then call the `insert` method of MongoDB to insert a large batch of documents at one time. The callback is the documents (with their `_id` fields set). If you have thousands of documents, you may want to use JavaScript's array `slice` to break the array into smaller chunks so that you don't cause a driver timeout with a really large `insert`.

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    , Server = require('mongodb').Server;

var allVariables = [ {
    ThingsToGet: [
        {
            first_thing: "SOMETHING ONE",
            second_thing: [[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 4], [4, 4], [5, "x"], [6, "x"]],
            third_thing: 0,
            fourth_thing: []
        },{
            first_thing: "SOMETHING TWO",
            second_thing: [[1, 0], [2, 5], [3, 4], [4, 4], [5, "x"], [6, "x"]],
            third_thing: 0,
            fourth_thing: []
        },{
            first_thing: "SOMETHING THREE",
            second_thing: [[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 4], [4, 4], [5, 2], [6, 2]],
            third_thing: 0,
            fourth_thing: []
        },
    ]
}
,
    {
        ThingsToGet: [
            {
                first_thing: "SOMETHING ONE",
                second_thing: [[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 4], [4, 4], [5, "x"], [6, "x"]],
                third_thing: 0,
                fourth_thing: []
            },{
                first_thing: "SOMETHING TWO",
                second_thing: [[1, 0], [2, 5], [3, 4], [4, 4], [5, "x"], [6, "x"]],
                third_thing: 0,
                fourth_thing: []
            },{
                first_thing: "SOMETHING THREE",
                second_thing: [[1, 0], [2, 0], [3, 4], [4, 4], [5, 2], [6, 2]],
                third_thing: 0,
                fourth_thing: []
            },
        ]
    }
];


mongo.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;
    var collection = db.collection('variables');

    // you may want to do them in batches rather than all at once
    collection.insert(allVariables, function(err,docs){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(docs) {
            console.log("Docs inserted: " + docs.length)
            // you could do something here with the docs
        }
    });
});
```

The other option would be to actually use the `json-decode` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)) functionality in PHP to load the JSON, and then insert the documents using the MongoDB PHP driver. You'll need to change the syntax of your JSON files to be pure [JSON](http://json.org/). For example, it can't have variable declarations in the file.

It might go something like this:

```
$bigJsonFile = file_get_contents('./variables.json', false)
$bigJsonObject = json_decode($json)
$collection->insert($bigJsonObject)
```